# phpでmysqlから取得したデータが空の状態です。

Tags: php

教本の通り（データベースとテーブルは違いますが）ソースを書いたのですが、取得したデータが空の状態になっています。
別の質問の回答で
$db->query("set names utf8");
を入力とあり、やってみましたが駄目でした。

ソースは以下の通りです。

```
<?php
    require_once 'Manager.php';  //データベースへの接続を行うソースファイル
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'; />
<title>登録済みデータ一覧</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>郵便番号</th><th>都道府県</th><th>住所</th><th>会社名</th><th>電話番号</th>
</tr>

<?php
try{
$db = connect();

//プリペアードステートメントの生成
$stt = $db->prepare('select zip_code,pref,com_address,com_name,tel_no from  address where pref like "富山県";');

echo "ここまで来ました。";

//プリペアードステートメントを実行
$stt->execute();

echo "kita";

//結果セットからレコードのデータをフェッチする
while($row = $stt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php $row["zip_code"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php $row["pref"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php $row["com_address"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php $row["com_name"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php $row["tel_no"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
$db = NULL;
}catch(PDOException $e){
    die("エラーが発生しました。:{$e->getMessage()}");
}
 echo "抜けた";
?>

</table>
</body>
```

【結果はこのように出力されました。】

[image: 結果はこのようになります]

どなたか、ご教授お願いします。

Comment: ソースコードの部分はスクリーンショットでなく、テキストとして質問に貼り付けて下さい。それにより検索なども可能になりますし、特定の色合いが苦手な方でも読めるようになります。その際、貼り付けたコードなどは[選択した上で `{}` ボタンをクリック](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2069/3054)して整形済みブロックにすると、インデントが保持され、`<` などの文字もそのまま使えるようになります。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。修正いたしました。

Comment: テーブルが複数列表示されているということはwhile文でのループ自体は回っていて(=データは取得できている)、その中の「列データを参照する」ところに問題があるのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

echoなど必要ではないでしょうか。

```
<td><?php $row["zip_code"]; ?></td>
```

↓

```
<td><?php echo $row["zip_code"]; ?></td>
```

Comment: echo を入れたらいけました。ありがとうございます。